# How to dynamically pass parameters from high-order function to callback function?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, parameters, callback, higher-order-functions

I have callback functions that take `n` parameters. `n` is dynamic. How can I pass `n` parameters dynamically from the higher-order function to callback functions?

```
const callbackFn1 = (para1, para2, para3) =>{
 //some code
}
const callbackFn2 = (para1, para2, para3, para4) =>{
 //some code
}
const hoFn = (callback, ...rest){
 return callback(rest[0], rest[1], rest[3],...,rest[n-1]) // how to pass like this?
}

hoFn(callbackFn1, para1, para2, para3)
hoFn(callbackFn2, para1, para2, para3, para4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function hoFn(callback, ...rest) {
  callback(rest);
}
hoFn((params) => {
  console.log(params);
}, "Lorem", "Ipsum", "lora")
```